# Chat doesn't load my feed

Tags: support, chat, feed

I have created a feed which I want to add to a room, but for some reason it doesn't work ™.

I have added [the feed](https://feedr.pieterhordijk.com/atom/6/room-11-regulars/feed.xml) to a [test room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18852/feedr-test), but it doesn't load the messages. I have validated the feed and everything (according to the w3c validator) [looks ok](http://validator.w3.org/feed/check.cgi?url=https%3A%2F%2Ffeedr.pieterhordijk.com%2Fatom%2F6%2Froom-11-regulars%2Ffeed.xml).

What is the reason my feed's posts doesn't show up in the room?

Comment: I don't know enough to help you, but the folks over at http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ might.

Comment: [Maybe SE doesn't support your SSL configuration](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=feedr.pieterhordijk.com)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Chat is failing to load your feed, throwing an error because the TLS handshake failed. Interestingly most browsers seem to be happy with your SSL setup, except for Firefox, which considers the connection to not be secure.

I'd guess the problem is that you're using a certificiate that's still signed using SHA1, which [won't be around for much longer](http://googleonlinesecurity.blogspot.de/2014/09/gradually-sunsetting-sha-1.html). The rest of the ciphersuite looks okay as far as I can tell (I'm anything but an SSL expert); AES_128_GCM with ECDHE_RSA is the same one that we use (e.g. when you connect to https://meta.stackexchange.com). But our certificate is SHA256-signed.

Comment: That is odd indeed, because when trying in my FF 33.1.1 windows 7 it happily accepts my certificate :(

Comment: Weird, FF works here.

Comment: @Braiam Are you sure? It loads it fine for me, but it says the connection is not encrypted.

Comment: +infinity for rejecting SHA1 signed certs. You are making the internet safer. Thank you.

Comment: Oh right, if I check the page info it says the page isn't encrypted.

Comment: Works for me http://imgur.com/PmMrGhE,4rjvxWw#1 :(

Comment: Considering my certificate is due for renewal in January either way I will go ahead and renew the thing now and find out whether that solves the issue. Will let you know whether it works and if not I will just bug you more :-) Thanks for looking into it for now.

Comment: @PeeHaa Let me know when you're done. Chat throttles back the requests to failing feeds, so it may take a while until it would try again. I can punch it a bit to retry earlier.

Comment: Hey @balpha. Sorry for the late reply. [I renewed my certificate and upgraded the algo](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=feedr.pieterhordijk.com). I as well have removed weak ciphers. I've added the feed to [our room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11/php) and everything works as expected now \o/. Thanks for your support!